# GeoWebCache Speed SQL Server Store

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, sql-server

How to increase GeoWebCache speed, Am using geoserver 2.7.2 for tile cache and data store creating from a SQL Server database it will take 1 day and above to complete cache and it terminated several time,am tring this using postgreSQL DB it will comparative faster than SQL server and it never terminate, what the reasons for that?

How increase GeoWebCache speed using data store from a SQL Server database?

Comment: we need to know a lot more about your setup before we can answer this. Most likely causes are lack of indexing or just that you are using an old version of SQL Server (2008 is particularly bad). Note you are actually trying to speed up GeoServer not GeoWebCache which just reads and writes tiles to disk.